# Need an app where I can clearly show the hierarchy/order my clients jobs are in so they can see which jobs are ahead of their jobs

Tags: software-recommendation, client-relations, applications, lists

**Ideally it would look like:**

- Priority 01: Calendar Project Edits
- Priority 02: Website Edits
- Priority 03: Sales Sheet Layout
- Etc. Etc. Etc.

Something very simple but shareable and easy to update. My clients never have any idea why their project is held back and this would be GOLD to show them a real time list like this.

Does this exist?

Thank you!

Comment: Google docs spreadsheet.

Comment: That's a good idea! My clients can also edit the order if they so desire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Google Docs

If the intention is to *share* the list....

Then just with that single factor being predominant, I'd suggest **Google Docs** which are designed to be easily shared. Then digging further if you want a list, perhaps with dates, turnaround times, or other items in a table-like structure, a **Google Doc Spreadsheet** seems to be a good choice.

---

### There is also [**Trello**](https://trello.com/?&aceid=&adposition=1t2&adgroup=54875434705&campaign=1407850971&creative=270028287524&device=c&keyword=trello&matchtype=e&network=g&placement=&ds_kids=p33213123835&ds_e=GOOGLE&ds_eid=700000001557344&ds_e1=GOOGLE&gclid=EAIaIQobChMInZSmtoDz3wIVLx6tBh0T5geAEAAYAiAAEgIkn_D_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) for project tracking.

I've found Trello helpful at times. It can take a bit more work to input a project because, being an app, they try and support everyone. There can often be too many fields to fill out when inputting. It's all personal flavor though.

---

Beyond Google Docs and Trello, I'd configure my own web page via **PHP/Mysql**. It's a simple enough set up to create a database and track items with date and/or priority flags. In fact, I set this up exactly for my own tracking when things get too hectic and I'm concerned a project may get "lost".

---

Note I'm really not a big proponent of Google Docs due to Google's data mining. And I, personally, would *never* share a list of my priorities with clients. I want every client to *feel* like they are my #1 priority. As soon as a client sees they are #4 or #8 on a list, they may feel "snubbed" and unimportant. It's one thing for a client to be unhappy about waiting. It's another for them to see, in writing, how low on a priority list their project is. I simply think sharing such information is a bad idea.

But.. for in-house use, with your own team, showing a list of your projects can be *very* helpful in keeping people from interrupting and pestering you when they are waiting for something.

Comment: Agree on all of this about Google Sheets. I already started setting one up.

Comment: I work in house so I am really looking to share this with my personal team. I should have clarified. The client will never actually see this list, just the Communications Specialists who give me the jobs.

Comment: @lazycarpenter Ahhhh...... personal team makes a difference :) Still not a fan of Google's data mining, but I'd be good with sharing the list in house and can see how overall helpful that would be. I used to do something similar when I was in-house.

Comment: The problem I run into is the old "What are you doing all day/" because all of my team members do not have line of site to my project load. They only see their own projects and don't care about other projects that cut in font of their own projects.

Comment: Note: I tried Monday.com but it was cumbersome and just didn't feel right.

Comment: Trello is pretty great too. Might give it a go for this scenario.